# Dealing with optionals in FSEventStreamRef API from Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to observe a folder to see if a file is created/modified/deleted etc. in that folder on Mac OS. I have read that what i want to use is the File System Events, but i can't get my code to work.

I have tried to read the [docs at apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_system_events) and read up on different posts on stackoverflow, but nothing i've found seem to be working on swift 4 and xcode 10.

```swift
    init(path: String) {
        let allocator: CFAllocator? = kCFAllocatorDefault

        // Create FSEventStream and return valid FSEventStreamRef
        // Alias FSEventStreamCallback - CFunction

        typealias FSEventStreamCallback = @convention(c) (ConstFSEventStreamRef, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, Int, UnsafeMutableRawPointer, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventFlags>, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventId>) -> Void


        let callback: FSEventStreamCallback = {
            (streamRef, clientCallBackInfo, numEvents, eventPaths, eventFlags, eventIds) -> Void in
            print ("changed")
            // handle file event
        }

        let context: UnsafeMutablePointer<FSEventStreamContext>? = nil
        let pathsToWatch: CFArray = [NSHomeDirectory() + path] as CFArray
        let sinceWhen: FSEventStreamEventId = UInt64(kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow)
        let latency: CFTimeInterval = 1.0
        let flags: FSEventStreamCreateFlags = UInt32(kFSEventStreamCreateFlagNone)
        let eventStream = FSEventStreamCreate(
            allocator,
            callback,
            context,
            pathsToWatch,
            sinceWhen,
            latency,
            flags
        )

        FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(eventStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode as! CFString)
        FSEventStreamStart(eventStream!)
    }
```

I either get the error

```
Value of optional type 'FSEventStreamRef?' (aka 'Optional<OpaquePointer>') must be unwrapped to a value of type 'FSEventStreamRef' (aka 'OpaquePointer')
```

when i try to build or

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

on runtime if i add a '!' to "eventStream"

What do i need to change to get it to run?

Comment: You need to unwrap the optional properly. Force unwrapping is failing because it's value is `nil`, and by force unwrapping, you explicitly old the compiler "Trust me, this optional totally isn't nil."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eventStream` must be unwrapped – preferably with optional binding, e.g.

```
guard let eventStream = FSEventStreamCreate(...) else {
     // handle error ...
}
```

But what actually causes your program to crash is the forced cast in

```
FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(..., CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode as! CFString)
```

`CFRunLoopMode` is *not* a `CFString` so that the forced `as! CFString` fails. It is a `struct CFRunLoopMode: RawRepresentable`, and the underlying `CFString` is obtained with the `rawValue` property:

```
FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(..., CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue)
```

*Remark:* `typealias FSEventStreamCallback` is already defined in the Core Services framework, there is no need to duplicate the definition in your class.